# Words counter with a hash

Tags: ruby, strings

My problem is the following: I wrote a method, which counts words and returns a hash. There is a Ruby idiom which was found by me in some of the forums discussions, which I don't understand.

Here is the whole code:

```
text = "bla bla blahh blahh"
def count_words(string)
  inp = string.downcase.scan(/\b[\'a-z]+\b/i).inject(Hash.new 0){|c,w| c[w]+=1;c }
  return inp
end
puts count_words(text)
```

Here is the idiom: `inject(Hash.new 0){|c,w| c[w]+=1;c }`

My concrete questions are the following:

1) How it understands when we should add 1 to the particular key?

2) As far as I understand "inject" method, "c" is some sort of counter. So how does it happen that we write c[w]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is about `inject` initial value when you give `Hash.new(0)`
   and call `c[w] += 1` in block it is expanded to `c[w] = c[w] + 1` as we said
   to `Hash` initializer if it has no key then key will set to `0` when
   first appeared.
2. `c` here is an accumulator and instance of `inject` initial value.
   accumulator value will be set to return value of the block after
   every turn. we are returning `c` because of this. it can be type of
   any object. `(1..10).inject(0) {|a,x| a + x }` for example it is
   `Fixnum` here.

Comment: thanks, but it's still unclear for me how can we use accumulator in the case different from working with a Fixnum object?

Comment: this is a good [blog post](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html) about `inject`.